# How to use developer determined free trial for in-app purchases in Play Store

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I am working on a Flutter app that offers a subscription with a base plan that costs $4.99. I want to give users a 1-week free trial, which I have set to "developer decision" in the Google Play Console, meaning I will decide when to offer the trial.

However, there is no mention in the documentation or the library docs of how a developer can decide if the trial should be offered.

I am using the `in_app_purchase plugin` to handle the subscription, but when the code is executed, it only offers the base price and not the free trial. Here's my current code that opens up the Play Store dialog to buy it at base price 4.99$:

```dart
    const Set<String> _kIds = <String>{'premium_monthly'};
    final ProductDetailsResponse response = await InAppPurchase.instance.queryProductDetails(_kIds);
    if (response.notFoundIDs.isNotEmpty) {
      print("response.notFoundIDs.isNotEmpty");
    }
    List<ProductDetails> products = response.productDetails;
    final ProductDetails product = products[0];
    final GooglePlayProductDetails details = product as GooglePlayProductDetails;

    // Check if an introductory price is available
    if (details.skuDetails.introductoryPrice != null &&
        details.skuDetails.priceAmountMicros > 0) {
      print("introductory Price: ${details.skuDetails.introductoryPrice}"); // Output: ""
      print('Free trial available: ${details.skuDetails.introductoryPriceCycles}'); // Output: 0
      print('Trial period: ${details.skuDetails.introductoryPricePeriod}'); // Output: ""
    } else {
      print('No free trial available');
    }

    final PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(productDetails: details);
    InAppPurchase.instance.buyConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam, autoConsume: false);
```

Please also take a look at the offer in Play Store Console.

[image: The Product in my Play Store Account]

[image: The Developer Determined trial offer in my Play Store Account]

Comment: did u find any way? I also still looking for this

Comment: @RahulZx I ultimately created two different offers, one that always offers trial, and the other one that never does. Then I used the logic in code to decide which product ID to use for each user.